# Static files not loading properly 50% of the time

Tags: google-app-engine

when i load my site from incognito (when static files are not caches), about 50% of the time some static files which are hosted on app engine are not showing up. one time it can be a CSS file and other times it's JS. in the console i see this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I have no idea why this happens and how to fix it.

Also, when you first go the page, you sometimes see a message saying the page is unavailable, and then immediately the page appears.

How to reproduce:
open this page on incognito (each time): http://alephz.com/
about 5 out of 10 times it should come up without CSS or JS

Comment: tried many times, keeping chrome console open. no errors, so your problem might be your local chrome install. did you disable all plugins/extensions ?

Comment: @koma i tested on other computers and other networks (browserstack) and i got the errors

Comment: certainly I can't see this issue at all.  I tried this and its working fine for me .

Comment: Page loads fine for me. Refreshed a dozen times. Any errors in the App Engine logs (400 calls for resources) Perhaps screenshots. Do CTRL-SHIFT-I, under the network tab do you see any errors?

Comment: @RyanB yes, there are network errors with the failed files. Don't just refresh, but close and open incognito, because the files are in your cache. in GAE log there is no request for the missing file

Comment: Re-opened 6-8 times and still loads properly. Have you tried from other PC's?

Comment: @RyanB like i said in a previous comment, yes, i tried several times from other computers/networks

Comment: Might be a regional thing, what country are you in?

Comment: @RyanB Israel. Also checked from browserstack which is usually EU for me

Comment: If GAE doesn't show any error (4XXX) nor success/redirect (2XX, 3XX) for the missing files, it means that the request didn't even reach the server. Can you track that down and share log screenshots?

Comment: It looks like there is a drop in the connection. which is not fullfilling the request.

Comment: Site is not opening. It just keep spinning and nothing appears. Sometimes, it is bizarre that a site cannot be loaded in an area. Ping works fine though!

Answer (score 0):

It might be the DNS prefetching having a problem. Try disabling it by adding `<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off">` into your header. Have not seen that being a problem for a while though.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is a certificate mismatch / expired certificate.

You can see [this](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/renderer/security_filter_peer.cc?pathrev=261323) for yourself in the code here.

Note in particular the use of the very constant you reference in the code on line 44 of the C++ file in above link:

```
case net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE:
```

The current version of this file is [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/renderer/security_filter_peer.cc&type=cs&sq=package:chromium&l=44). The error status `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` may not any longer be on line 44 but the error code still exists in the SSL certificate portion of the code.

But as you are requesting the resources over SSL it is likely the certificate is invalid. Either it is self-signed and has not been added to your browser/OS exceptions or it is otherwise invalid.

Try the URI directly in the same browser and inspect the certificate.

This is in no way related to jQuery, JavaScript or CSS directly.

Comment: Hi Moshe Shaham, please find the answer updates. Hope it will be helpful for you